# Problem using select-object @{name="Name"; expression=$variable}

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I tried something like this but it never gives the values, where my ifile.csv contains two columns displayname, grpmail

```
Import-Csv "E:\ifile.csv" | foreach {get-distributionGroupMember -Identity $_.displayname | select-Object @{Name= GroupName; Expression = {$_.grpmail}}, Recipienttype, Primarysmtpaddress} | Export-csv -no typeinformation "E:\Ofile.csv"
```

Can anyone advise me what I am doing wrong
I am expecting ofile.csv with 3 columns as GroupName, Recipienttype, Primarysmtpaddress

i get values for Recipienttype, Primarysmtpaddress columns but GroupName column is always empty.

Comment: There is much that's irritating in your code. From code-highlighting in Powershell ISE alone you should be able to identify some problems. I also don't believe that your code is running without throwing any errors. Your basic approach is correct though.

Comment: Is the delimiter of the csv `,` or something else?

Comment: Please test this: `Import-Csv "E:\ifile.csv" | foreach { $_.displayname ; $_.grpmail  } | fl `

Answer (score 3):

It's because your `$_` in the pipeline has changed to the result of your `get-distributiongroupmember` and is no longer your CSV file input.

Try this instead:

```
Import-Csv "E:\ifile.csv" | foreach {
$gname = $_.grpmail
Get-distributionGroupMember -Identity $_.displayname | Select @{Name= GroupName; Expression = {$gname}}, Recipienttype, Primarysmtpaddress} | Export-csv -no typeinformation "E:\Ofile.csv"
```

I've just split lines 2 and 3 to make it easier to read - you can put a semi-colon after `$gname = $_.grpmail` instead if you like.

As a general note, I like to assign specific variable names to pipeline objects to see what I'm actually working with, especially if they're being transformed on the way. Also, I like to use multiple lines to better see what's happening

```
foreach ($g in (Import-Csv "E:\ifile.csv")) {
    Get-distributionGroupMember -Identity $g.displayname | 
    Select @{Name= GroupName; Expression = {$g.grpmail}},Recipienttype,Primarysmtpaddress
} | Export-csv -notypeinformation "E:\Ofile.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
As per T-Me's suggestion, try this:

```
Import-Csv "E:\ifile.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $grpmail = $_.grpmail
    get-distributionGroupMember -Identity $_.displayname | Select-Object @{ Name = 'GroupName'; `
                                                                            Expression = "$grpmail" }, `
                                                                            Recipienttype, Primarysmtpaddress
} | Export-csv -no typeinformation "E:\Ofile.csv"
```

Comment: This won't fix the problem but write the string `grpmail` in the field of `GroupName` for every line...

Comment: So like, 
Import-Csv "E:\ifile.csv" | ForEach-Object {
$grpmail = $_.grpmail
    get-distributionGroupMember -Identity $_.displayname | Select-Object @{ Name = 'GroupName'; 
                                                                            Expression = "$grpmail" },
                                                                            Recipienttype, Primarysmtpaddress
} | Export-csv -no typeinformation "E:\Ofile.csv"

Comment: Yes now it's correct and would work. But now it's the same as the answer of @trix

Comment: You don't need the backquotes.  Yes, the curlybrace was in the wrong place in the select.

Comment: I mean you can continue a line with just the comma.  You can take out the semicolon too.

Comment: Sorry, was my comment that difficult to understand? Yes, as a one-liner, it's `Import-Csv "E:\ifile.csv" | ForEach-Object { $grpmail = $_.grpmail; get-distributionGroupMember -Identity $_.displayname | Select-Object @{ Name = 'GroupName'; Expression = "$grpmail" }, Recipienttype, Primarysmtpaddress } | Export-csv -no typeinformation "E:\Ofile.csv"`